# Instagram tag is global scope or user scope

Tags: instagram

I am not sure whether instagram tag is global scope or user scope

when I call the api below, I got the same result, no matter what the access_token I use.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{theTag}/media/recent?access_token={mytoken}

https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/search?q={theTag}&access_token={myToken}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of the Instagram API endpoints you referenced are global. They will not return tags just for the authenticated user. I am not aware of a way of also filtering by user when searching by tag or when searching for tags.